# Как архивировать файлы в архив zip\rar?

Tags: c#

Есть список файлов, как архивировать их в rar/zip, и получить строку где находится архив с этими файлами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть класс [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx). Можно использовать его. 
Есть библиотеки [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) или [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/).

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    // оставляем комментарий к архиву
    zip.Comment = "Archive created by " + User.Identity.Name + " at " + DateTime.Now;

    // добавляем незапароленный файл в архив
    zip.AddFile(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "ReadMe.txt");

    // устанавливаем пароль к архиву
    zip.Password = password;

    // добавляем файл в архив, этот файл будет доступен только с вводом пароля, т.к. выше был установлен пароль
    zip.AddFile(databaseFileName);

    // установка уровня сжатия
    zip.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.BestCompression;

    // сохраняем архив
    zip.Save(databaseFileName + ".zip");
}
```

Распаковка архива:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFile))
          zip.ExtractAll(siteFolder, existingFileAction);
```

Работа библиотеки меня вполне устраивает, но при сжатии файлов в несколько гигабайт использовал:

```
zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
```

Answer (score 2):

Приведу пример как упаковать "потоково" в zip. Мне нужна была поддержка NET2.0 и к тому же, хочу показать внутреннюю структуру файла.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
public class Demo{
    public static int ZipDeflate(System.IO.Stream dest, string FileName, System.IO.Stream src, System.IO.Stream tail,int offset){
        /* zip-архив двупроходный, содержит тело и "хвост"
           нужно записать "все" файлы через ZipStore, хвост запишется в tail*/            
        System.IO.MemoryStream deflate = new MemoryStream();
        UInt32[] CrcTable = new UInt32[256];
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        uint Crc32 = 0 ^ 0xffffffff;
        int size = (FileName == null) ? 0 : (14 + 12 + 4 + FileName.Length);
        uint dt2 = (uint)((dt.Second / 2) | (dt.Minute << 5) | (dt.Hour << 11) | (dt.Day << 16) | (dt.Month << 21) | ((dt.Year - 1980) << 25));  /*DOS time*/
        uint POLYNOMIAL = 0xEDB88320, remainder = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < 256; i++)
            {
                remainder = (uint)i;
                for (uint bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit) remainder = ((remainder & 1) != 0) ? ((remainder >> 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL) : (remainder >> 1);
                CrcTable[i] = remainder;
            }
        src.Position = 0;
        using (System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream ds = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(deflate, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress,true))
            do{
                i = src.Read(buf, 0, 4096);
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++) Crc32 = CrcTable[(Crc32 ^ buf[j]) & 0xff] ^ (Crc32 >> 8);                  
                ds.Write(buf,0,i);                    
            } while (i == 4096);                                                
        deflate.Position=0;
    src.Position = 0;
        Crc32 ^= 0xffffffff;
        dest.Write(new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x03, 4, 0x14 , 0, 0, 0 , 8/*deflate*/, 0 }, 0, 10);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(new uint[] { dt2, Crc32, (uint)deflate.Length /*compressed size*/,(uint) src.Length, (uint)FileName.Length }, 0, buf, 0, 20);
        dest.Write(buf,0, 20);
        dest.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FileName), 0, FileName.Length);            
        do
        {
            i = deflate.Read(buf, 0, 4096); /*Запись "тела" (deflate stream)*/
            if (i != 0) dest.Write(buf, 0, i);
            Console.Write("len=" + i);
            size += i;
        } while (i == 4096);

        long len = (long)tail.Length;             /*Обработка хвоста*/
        int offs = 0;
        int count = 1;
        if (len != 0){
            tail.Position = len - 12;
            tail.Read(buf, 0, 12);
            count = ((int)BitConverter.ToInt16(buf, 0)) + 1;
            offs = BitConverter.ToInt32(buf, 6);
            tail.Position = len - 22; /*Следующий central-dir */
        };
        count = count * 65536 + count; /*Запись central-dir*/           
        Buffer.BlockCopy(new uint[] { 0x2014B50,0x200B23,0x80000/*deflate*/, dt2, Crc32, (uint)deflate.Length,(uint) src.Length, (uint)FileName.Length,0, 0x81, 0,0 }, 0, buf, 0, 42);
        tail.Write(buf,0,42);
        tail.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(offset),0, 4);  /* ? */
        tail.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FileName), 0, FileName.Length);
        len = (int)tail.Length;   /*Запись endof-centraldir*/
        Buffer.BlockCopy(new int[] { 0x6054B50,0,count,(int)len,(int)(offs+size),0 }, 0, buf, 0, 22);
        tail.Write(buf, 0, 22);
        tail.Position = 0;
        return size;
    }
public static void Main(string[] args){
    Stream dest = System.IO.File.Create("1.zip");
    MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream();
    MemoryStream tail = new MemoryStream();
    //MemoryStream tail = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    mm.Write(new byte[] { 65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65 },0, 10);
    mm.Position = 0;
    int offs =ZipDeflate(dest,"1.txt",mm,tail,0); /*Запись файла*/
    // mm.Position = 0; offs += ZipDeflate(dest,"2.txt",mm,tail,offs);/*Второй файл*/
    dest.Write(tail.ToArray(),0,(int)tail.Length);// Запись "хвоста"
    dest.Close();
}
}
```

Информация про структуру zip тут http://www.sql.ru/forum/1053806/razbor-zip-fayla

И для файла который получился приведу "разбор" структуры 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И напоследок особенности такого подхода:

- размер архива или "разжатого" файла в архиве  - до 2Gb, русские имена - нет
- Если убрать `deflate` и поменять 8(deflate) на 0, архив будет stored.
- в NET 2.0 маленькие (до 1kb) файлы плохо пакуются, т.к. добавляется 100байтная шапка, но функциональность не теряется.