# c# DeflateStream глюк сжатия 100байт?

Tags: c#, .net

Как заворачивать поток (файлы) в DeflateStream? С распаковкой проблем не было, первый раз пакую - получаю из 10 байт длинну "сжатого" пакета 104 (смешно), а уже этот пакет декомпресии не подлежит? DeflateStream не пакует, или я что-то упустил?
Привожу кусок кода

```
  using System;
using System.IO;
public class Demo{
 public static void Main(string[] args){
   MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream();// Исходный поток    
   mm.Write(new byte[] { 65,65,65,65,65, 65,65,65,65,65 },0, 10); // Пакую еденицы 1111111111 10байт
   mm.Position = 0;
   MemoryStream deflate =  new MemoryStream(); // сжатый поток
   using (System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream ds = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(deflate, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress,true))
     ds.Write(mm.ToArray(),0,(int)mm.Length); // сжимаю
   Console.WriteLine(deflate.Length); // смотрю длинну упаковки (должно по-идее быть 5 байт если упаковать zip и глянуть размер)
   byte[] x = new byte [100];
   int q=0;
   deflate.Position = 0;
   using (System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream d2 = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(deflate, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
         q=d2.Read(x, 0, 100);// разжимаю


   Console.WriteLine(q); // размер "разпакованого"
  Console.WriteLine(x[0]); // Первый символ

}
}
```

Вместо 5 10 байт выдаёт 104 10 (может быть не 5, может быть от 3 ну до... 20). Исключения нету. Т.е. это чисто глюк дот-нета.

Сжатие zip [получилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681886/17974), при этом и 104 и 5 байт архиваторы нормально едят. А вопрос был, оказывается при паковке и разпаковке "сжатый" поток указывается в конструкторе. Во втором `new DeflateStream` я перепутал поток, поставив туда пустой `new MemoryStream` т.е. было `var d3=new MemoryStream(); new DeflateStream(d3,Decompress)` , надеюсь мою ошибку не повторят.

Comment: Слишком мало пакуешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy а что, есть на deflate-метод минимум? Сейчас 100 попробую:) для 100 ответ 105 и 0. Странно /

Comment: Я нашёл что поправить в Read нужно массив

Comment: @nick_n_a запустил ваш код (после исправления чтения во временный массив, т.е. тот, что сейчас в вопросе) - все читает правильно, в массиве, выдает 5, 10, 65.

Comment: Я кажется понял в чём дело. NET2.0 даёт 104 байта, а NET4.0 даёт 5 байт.

Comment: Попробую ещё поколдовать с 2.0, но наверно уже нет смысла.

Comment: @nick_n_a в 4.5 алгоритм поменялся, об этом сказано на странице класса  в msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, надо понимать, что Deflate-компрессия - это смесь Хаффмана и Лемпеля-Зива. Где-то для всего этого надо хранить заголовки и таблицы (дерево кодов Хаффмана).

С чего вы взяли, что должно получится в итоге 5 байт? Я так понимаю, что вы просто представили, что оно станет в 2 раза меньше? Спешу вас огорчить, сжать можно далеко не всё.

Поэтому к вашим гипотетическим 5 байтам, прибавляются сверху служебные данные, которые и дают 104 байта (на самом деле должно быть меньше, что указывает на какую-то еще ошибку или слабую реализацию). А если сжать 100 байт, то получается примерно такой же объем данных (энтропия аналогична), и уже не так плохо в общих чертах. А вот если сжать 1000 байт, то будет даже профит заметен.

Comment: *С чего вы взяли, что должно получится в итоге 5 байт?*  Cоздаю файл, пишу туда еденицы 10 штук без переносов. Пакую - смотрю в архиваторе свойства Compressed-Size = 5. Можете у себя под Windows повторить - получите 5.

Comment: А у меня получается 25. Паковщиков в мире много, даже если они используют одинаковый формат сжатия, алгоритмы могут отличаться. А в конкретно этом случае, полагаю, еще и некорректно отображаются результаты сжатия