# Почему при архивации файл получается по размеру больше чем исходный файл

Tags: c#

Написал несколько методов, читаем частями файл, далее сжимаем его, все кладем в очередь с готовыми блоками и потом блоки пишем в файл, использую сжатие данных и на выходе файл получается по размеру больше, чем исходный файл , подскажите почему так?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication57
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 string path = @"d:\Black Widow.m4a";
 string path_compres = @"d:\Compress.gz";



// создаем очередь c блоками ланных
        Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> queue_block = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>();
// создаем очередь с готовыми обработанными блоками
        Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> readyQueue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>();


// открываем поток
            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))


// добавляем в очередь блоки

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> block in Read_Blockk(fs))
        {
            queue_block.Enqueue(block);

        }



    // сжимаем и добавляем в готовую очередь        
            while (queue_block.Count>0)
            {
                var block = queue_block.Dequeue();
                var compressionBlock = COmpress(block.Key, block.Value);
                readyQueue.Enqueue(compressionBlock);

            }

     // пишем в файл блоки



            while (readyQueue.Count!=0)
            {

                Write_Final_File(path_compres,readyQueue.Dequeue().Value);
            }



Console.ReadKey();



        }



        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,byte[]>> Read_Blockk(Stream stream)
        {
            const int size_block=1024 * 1024; // определяем размер буфера=1мб

            int index = 0; // номер блока
            while (stream.Position<stream.Length)
            {
                // выделяем память под массив буффера.
                byte[] buffer=new byte[System.Math.Min(size_block,stream.Length-stream.Position)];

                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                yield return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(index++,buffer);
            }

        }



        public static KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> COmpress(int index,byte[] block)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (var gzStream=new GZipStream(ms,CompressionMode.Compress))
            {

                int ind = index;
                gzStream.Write(block,0,block.Length);
                gzStream.Close();

                 return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(ind++,ms.ToArray());

                }

            }

        public static void Write_Final_File(string path,    byte[] ReadyBlock)
        {
            using (var fsWrite = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))

            fsWrite.Write(ReadyBlock,0,ReadyBlock.Length);


        }


        }



    }
```

Comment: Варианта 3. 1)Либо размер маленький. Кроме сжатия ещё пиутся заголовки, заголовки тоже требуют места.  2) Содержимое данным алгоритмом не может быть сжато или попытка сжать повторно (уже сжатая информация как правило не сжимается, т.е. не сожмется jpg, mp3, и т д). 3)Банально глюк архиватора - строит расширеную таблицу вместо короткой. Я ловил такой [глюк](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681551/c-deflatestream-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-100%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82)

Comment: @nick_n_a сжимаю mp3, все сжимается я даже раром разжимаю и оно играет)), только вопрос с весом файла меня беспокоит, на чем лучше проверить именно сжатие,какие данные сжиматься будут хорошо

Comment: эээ вы путаете `rar` и `zip`, если вы сжали `rar`, а говорите что `zip` не сжимается - то это как-то не логично. `zip` чуть беднее. Берите тогда rar-библиотеку (если её реально достать) и ею сжимайте, указаным методом сжатия (BEST).

Comment: mp3 сложно упаковывать нормально. Если сможете быстро хотя бы на 20-30 процентов паковать - будет очень хорошо. А вот потестировать можно на обычных текстовых файлах - они легко должны в 2-3 раза сжиматься.

Comment: @nick_n_a раром я просто проверил,что  оно разжимается и все блоки встали правильно

Comment: Есть же готовы решения для С# с зипом и раром кстати, поищите на гитхабе

Comment: Почитайте про методы сжатия без потерь - в деталях - тогда можно обсуждать конкретный алгоритм. *Алгоритмы сжатия без потерь* строятся на таблицах, на совпадениях, как правило. В общем - чем меньше "повторов" в файле - тем тяжелее построить маленькую таблицу "сокращений". Таблицы "сокращений" растут, и размер ссылок на них растёт - как итог - растёт архив + размер шапки. Умные "компрессоры" если не могут сжать - ставят метод "copy". А не очень умные - раздувают таблицу - и файл может выйти и 120% и 150% от исходного.

Comment: Вопросы должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. Что вы сжимаете, чем сжимаете, как, что получаете, что ожидаете получить, почему ожидаете именно это а не другое - это все нужные детали ..

Comment: [Анти-велосипед](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress) SharpCompress :) нет глубоково смысла писать очередную обёртку вокруг родного `Compress`, если требуется качество сжатия, надо брать соответствующие инструменты.

Comment: В .NET 3.5 (почти уверен, что используется именно эта версия) алгоритм Deflate, который использует GZipStream реализован неудачно и размер многих типов файлов действительно растет. В 4.0 и выше все значительно лучше. Я проверял на PDF (тоже плохо жмутся, если внутри сканы страниц), в первом случае размер доходил до 150% от оригинала, во втором ни на одном из файлов разу не превысил 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если верить [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Функциональные возможности сжатия в DeflateStream и GZipStream
>   предоставляется в виде потока. Данные считываются на основе байт за
>   байтом, поэтому невозможно выполнить несколько проходов для
>   определения наилучшего метода сжатия целых файлов или больших блоков
>   данных. DeflateStream И GZipStream лучше всего используются классы
>   несжатого источников данных. Если исходные данные уже сжаты,
>   использование этих классов может действительно увеличить размер
>   потока.