# stm32f3 - как получить правильный CRC32?

Tags: stm32

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие настройки нужно сделать в Cube, чтобы `HAL_CRC_Calculate()` считал правильно crc32?

Answer (score 0):

Сам частично отвечаю:

```
char * stt = "ABCD"; 
uint8_t szf=strlen(stt);
for (int i=0;i<szf;i+=4){
    CRC->DR=(stt[i]<<24)|(stt[i+1]<<16)|(stt[i+2]<<8)|(stt[i+3]);
}
uint32_t k = ~(CRC->DR); // == DB1720A5
```

Отлично работает, когда количество байт в строке кратно 4-м. 
Попытки подставить в недостающие до 4-х байты, значения 0х00 или 0xFF - к успеху не привели. 
Что делать, когда длина строки не кратна 4?

После долгих изысков, ответ выглядит так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат

```
uint32_t i = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc,(uint32_t *)stt,strlen(stt));
printf("\r\n-----------------------------------------------------------");
printf("\r\n\"ABC\" - CRC=%d, or as Hex=%08x, and inverted Hex CRC=%08x",i,i,~i);
printf("\r\n-----------------------------------------------------------");
//-----------------------------------------------------------
//"ABC" - CRC=1551695031, or as Hex=5c7cfcb7, 
// and inverted Hex CRC= a3830348 <-ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ - ИНВЕРТИРОВАННЫЙ!!!
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Если вопрос ещё актуальный, у вас не crc32, пример с crc32 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421101/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-zip-rar/681886 либо используйте пример, или ваш алгоритм имеет какое-то другое название.