# Как извлечь файл и скопировать в другой ZIP?

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

Перебираю архив:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read("c:\temp\MyZip.zip"))
{
   foreach (ZipEntry file in zip)                                            
   {
     file.Extract("c:\Temp\MyFolder", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently); //извлечение в указанную папку
   }
}
```

Можно ли извлечь файл в память, а потом поместить в другой архив?

Comment: Можно поискать библиотеки,  можно попытаться разобрать файл, и перебросить данные из одного zip-файла в другой даже не разпаковывая файл - пример разбора - [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681886/17974)

Comment: По идее `ZipArchive` и `ZipArchiveEntry` позволяют создавать `ZipArchiveEntry` читать и писать в них используя Stream.

Comment: Вот пример записи в поток https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346(v=vs.110).aspx меняя CreateEntry на GetEntry  и ещё пару изменений с Stream - получится чтение. Немного преобразований - и ваша задача решена.