# Как связаны zlib, gzip и zip? Что у них общего и какие у них отличия?

Tags: zip, png, gzip, сжатие, zlib

Алгоритм сжатия, используемый в *zlib*, почти тот же, что и в *gzip* и *zip*. Чем они отличаются?

Comment: Хочу поделиться структурой zip http://i.stack.imgur.com/xKZEV.gif из http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421101/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-zip-rar/681886

Comment: А при чем тут PNG собственно, если вы про алгоритмы, а не про имплементации же?

Comment: @Kromster при том, что мы тут всё-таки и про имплементации тоже. Библиотека zlib пошла из png, и формат zlib появился одновременно с png и впервые использован в png (если я правильно понял всю эту историю)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*tl;dr:*

[zip](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) — формат архивов, использующий, как правило, алгоритм [Deflate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951) для сжатия; zip-архив может содержать несколько файлов, которые сжимаются отдельно друг от друга. [gzip](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) сжимает ровно один файл (этим одним файлом может быть tar-архив) и тоже использует алгоритм Deflate. [Библиотека zlib](http://zlib.net/) реализует Deflate и используется в zip, gzip, [png](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) и многих других приложениях.

---

Формат [zip](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) был разработан Филом Кацем как открытый формат, но его реализация, PKZIP, была условно-бесплатной (shareware). В этом формате архива хранятся файлы и структура каталогов, и каждый файл сжимается независимо от других файлов. Файлы и структура каталогов также могут быть зашифрованы.

Формат ZIP поддерживает несколько методов сжатия:

```
0 - The file is stored (no compression)
1 - The file is Shrunk
2 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 1
3 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 2
4 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 3
5 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 4
6 - The file is Imploded
7 - Reserved for Tokenizing compression algorithm
8 - The file is Deflated
9 - Enhanced Deflating using Deflate64(tm)
10 - PKWARE Data Compression Library Imploding (old IBM TERSE)
11 - Reserved by PKWARE
12 - File is compressed using BZIP2 algorithm
13 - Reserved by PKWARE
14 - LZMA (EFS)
15 - Reserved by PKWARE
16 - Reserved by PKWARE
17 - Reserved by PKWARE
18 - File is compressed using IBM TERSE (new)
19 - IBM LZ77 z Architecture (PFS)
97 - WavPack compressed data
98 - PPMd version I, Rev 1
```

Методы с 1 по 7 являются историческими и не используются. Методы с 9 по 98 добавлены относительно недавно и используются нечасто. Единственным широко распространённым методом является метод 8, [Deflate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951) и, в некоторой степени, метод 0, который просто хранит файлы без сжатия. Большинство zip-файлов, с которыми вы столкнётесь, будут использовать только методы 8 и 0.

[Стандарт ISO/IEC 21320-1:2015 для файловых контейнеров](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000361.shtml) является ограниченным форматом zip, используемым в файлах Java (.jar), Office Open XML (Microsoft Office .docx, .xlsx, .pptx), Office Document Format (.odt, .ods, .odp) и EPUB (.epub). Этот стандарт допускает только методы сжатия 0 и 8, а также имеет другие ограничения вроде отсутствия шифрования или подписей.

Примерно в 1990 году [группа Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/) написала переносимые и свободные реализации утилит `zip` и `unzip` с поддержкой сжатия Deflate и распаковки более старых форматов. Это значительно расширило использование формата `.zip`.

В начале 90-х [формат gzip](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) был разработан для замены Unix-утилиты `compress`. Утилита `compress` сжимала ровно один файл и добавляла к файлу расширение `.Z`. Она использовала алгоритм LZW, который в то время защищался патентами, что затрудняло его использование. Хотя некоторые конкретные реализации Deflate были запатентованы Филом Кацем, сам формат патентами не защищается, так что можно написать реализацию Deflate без нарушения патентов. Утилита `gzip` была задумана как прозрачная замена утилиты `compress` и фактически может распаковывать сжатые `compress`ом данные. `gzip` при сжатии добавляет расширение `.gz` к имени файла. `gzip` использует формат сжатия Deflate, который позволяет сжимать немного лучше чем `compress`, быстро распаковывается и проверяет целостность данных с помощью CRC-32. Заголовок формата gzip также позволяет хранить исходное имя файла и время его изменения.

Утилита `compress` сжимает ровно один файл, и для сжатия нескольких файлов с сохранением атрибутов и структуры каталогов обычно создавались архивы `tar`, которые затем сжимались с помощью `compress` для получения `.tar.Z` файла. Чтобы не сжимать всё вручную, утилита `tar` имела и до сих пор имеет опцию для автоматического включения сжатия с помощью `compress`; с появлением `gzip` также добавилась опция для включения gzip-сжатия и создания `.tar.gz` файлов. Архивы `.tar.gz` сжимаются лучше чем `zip`, так как файлы сжимаются не по отдельности и gzip имеет возможность эффективнее работать с избыточностью, особенно если в архиве много мелких файлов. `.tar.gz` широко распространён в Unix из-за его хорошей переносимости, но есть и более эффективные методы сжатия, так что могут встретиться архивы `.tar.bz2` и `.tar.xz`.

В отличие от `.tar`, `.zip` архивы хранят список файлов отдельно в конце файла. С учётом того, что каждый файл сжимается независимо, это позволяет прочитать отдельные файлы в архиве без распаковки всего архива целиком. А архив `.tar` должен быть распакован и прочитан целиком, чтобы даже просто увидеть список файлов в архиве, и это создаёт трудности в некоторых ситуациях.

Вскоре после появления gzip, примерно в середине 1990-х годов, те же проблемы с патентами поставили под вопрос бесплатное использование формата изображений `.gif`, очень широко используемого на досках объявлений (BBS) и во всемирной паутине (WWW — новинка того времени). Так что небольшая группа создала PNG — формат изображений со сжатием без потерь — чтобы заменить GIF. PNG тоже использует формат Deflate для сжатия. Чтобы способствовать широкому использованию формата PNG, были созданы две свободные библиотеки: [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) реализует все функции формата PNG, а [zlib](http://zlib.net/) предоставляет код сжатия и распаковки для использования в libpng и для других приложений. zlib был адаптирован из кода gzip.

Все упомянутые патенты уже истекли.

Библиотека zlib поддерживает Deflate, а также три обёртки (wrapping) для потоков Deflate. К ним относятся: отсутствие обёртки вообще («сырой» Deflate), обёртка zlib, который используется в блоках данных формата PNG, и обёртка gzip. Основное различие между обёртками zlib и gzip в том, что zlib-обёртка более компактна: всего 6 байт против как минимум 18 байт для gzip, а проверка целостности Adler-32 выполняется быстрее, чем CRC-32, который используется в gzip. Сырой метод Deflate используется программами, которые читают и записывают формат `.zip`, который по-своему работает с данными Deflate.

Библиотека zlib используется очень широко в том числе в качестве реализации формата gzip; например, она используется в большинстве браузеров и веб-серверов для сжатия передаваемых в HTTP данных (при этом обычно используется формат gzip, так как с форматом zlib [возникли некоторые исторические трудности](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856879)).

Разные реализации Deflate могут сжимать одни и те же данные с разной эффективностью, о чем свидетельствует наличие выбираемых уровней сжатия, которые позволяют выбирать между эффективностью сжатия и затраченным временем. zlib и PKZIP - не единственные реализации Deflate. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) или [zopfli](http://github.com/google/zopfli) могут затратить очень много времени, чтобы сжать данные на несколько процентов эффективнее чем zlib. Утилита [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/), многопоточная реализация gzip, может использовать zlib (уровни сжатия 1-9) или zopfli (уровень сжатия 11) и несколько уменьшает затрачиваемое время с помощью сжатия больших файлов на нескольких ядрах процессора.

---

<sup>*Слегка вольный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765054) от [Mark Adler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180620/mark-adler) на enSO с некоторыми дополнениями.*</sup>