# C#. Запаковать в tar без сжатия

Tags: c#, библиотеки, архивация

Собственно, требуется запаковать папку в .tar без потери скорости на распаковку сжатием.

ЯП: C# (.NET Framework 4.6)

Как это сделать?

Видел over 100500 примеров tar.gz, но он мне НЕ подходит :(

Можете помочь?

Comment: `но он мне НЕ подходит` почему?

Comment: @tym32167 скорость распаковки

Comment: Какую помощь вы от нас ожидаете? Что мы угадаем, какие из 100500 примеров вы видели и подскажем 100501вый? Ваши критерии слабоформализуемы и плохо вербализованы - угадать, что за ответ вам понравится можно только случайно.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, скорость распаковки зависит не только от типа сжатия, но и степени сжатия. Поставьте минимальное сжатие и будет вам "скорость".

Comment: @AK мне нужна запаковка именно tar, а не .tar.gz - примеры все по tar.gz (TRZ), а простого tar без сжатия нет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ все равно она будет ниже, чем обычный tar

Comment: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/GZip-and-Tar-Samples - там есть примеры для нежатого tar

Comment: Напишите скрипт в PowerShell (в win 10 есть утилита tar), затем имплементируйте скрипт в C#

Comment: Если хoтите без лишних либ - читайте доку, например http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man4/tar.4.asp Берите stream и пишите обвертку. Я писал stored и deflate для zip тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681886/17974 Аналогично можно переделать под ваши нужды. И укажите в вопросе "хочу самописную реализацию" возможно у кого-то валяется. Нужен хекс редактор, и несколько пробных сборок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void AddDirectoryFilesToTar(TarArchive tarArchive, string sourceDirectory, bool recurse)
{
    TarEntry tarEntry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(sourceDirectory);
    tarArchive.WriteEntry(tarEntry, false);


    string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory);
    foreach (string filename in filenames)
    {
        tarEntry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(filename);
        tarArchive.WriteEntry(tarEntry, true);
    }

    if (recurse)
    {
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectory);
        foreach (string directory in directories)
            AddDirectoryFilesToTar(tarArchive, directory, recurse);
    }
}

private void CreateTar(string tgzFilename, string sourceDirectory)
{
    Stream outStream = File.Create(tgzFilename);
    TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(outStream);
    tarArchive.RootPath = sourceDirectory.Replace('\\', '/');
    if (tarArchive.RootPath.EndsWith("/"))
        tarArchive.RootPath = tarArchive.RootPath.Remove(tarArchive.RootPath.Length - 1);
    AddDirectoryFilesToTar(tarArchive, sourceDirectory, true);
    tarArchive.Close();
}
```

НО! Нужно добавить **SharpZipLib**