# Как объединить несколько архивов?

Tags: c#, zip

Есть сервисы, которые пакуют zip архивы. Сервисы мои, т.е. могу им помочь формировать *правильные* архивы, если потребуется.

Есть желание некоторые архивы объединять, т.е. сервис1 создает архив1 с файл1, сервис2 создает архив2 с файл2. Хочется, чтобы условный сервис3 мог взять архив1 и архив2 и без лишних действий по перепаковке мог создать архив3 с файл1 и файл2 внутри.

Почитал по формату zip, по многотомным архивам (терминология разнится, сюда же - split и multi-part). По идее, формат очень похож на поток - есть ощущение, что можно просто слепить входные архивы один за другим и поправить End of central directory record (EOCD) у итогового архива.

Может есть готовые решения? Повтыкал в DotNetZip - он умеет в многотомные, а вот просто "склеить" два архива вроде не умеет.

Comment: Я разобрал структуру http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681886/17974 но говового решения под такую задачу - нету. Думаю данный разбор при должных навыках вам поможет. У zip ссылка на центральную директорию в самом хвосте (или под хвостом))))

Comment: @nick_n_a на вики в принципе весь формат разобран, но велосипед сильно не хочется делать, перепаковывать даже проще, имхо =)

Comment: Теоретически - нужно разделить - головы отдельно, хвосты отдельно, головы - по-обьединять, хвосты - поменять смещения и ссылки многотомности.. и по-обьединять. хвостовой заголовок - в последнюю очередь. На практике....

Comment: а в чем проблема с простой перепаковкой?

Comment: @tym32167 на большом объеме - лишние расходы ресурсов (как минимум CPU). Причем, то апи что я успел глянуть - не дает просто прицепить уже упакованные записи, пакует заново.